# On click, bootstrap click button funciton doesn't execute Meteor.call function (on android 4.1.2 browser)

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I've got a button.

```
<button type="button" id="mybutton" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
```

And 'click' function in my client/client.js

```
Template.index.events({
'click #mybutton' : function () {
  // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
    Meteor.call('voteMe', some parameters, function(error,result){
      if (error){
        console.log(error);
      }
      else{
        console.log(result);
      }
    });
    $(".testing").css({'display':'none'});
    $(".voted").css({'display':'block'});
},
//Here some other functions
```

And it works, but on android 4.1.2 browser it doesn't call 'voteMe' function, hovewer these lines works

```
$(".testing").css({'display':'none'});
$(".voted").css({'display':'block'});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is there anything in the browser console?  And are you positive that it's executing the jQuery from the `click` function rather than achieving the same effect elsewhere?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with Meteor 0.8.0, where the Meteor.call callback function is never called on the Android browser (it works in Chrome on the same device) - did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry - not enough reputation yet to comment so posting an answer:

This may be the same problem as I posted here:

[FIXED - Meteor app wrapped in cordova does not see same published data as browser on same device or simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372582/fixed-meteor-app-wrapped-in-cordova-does-not-see-same-published-data-as-browse)

I have provided an answer there that may help you.